# Alpha has problem when export as png

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

Whenever I export a render result as png, the alpha(translucent)parts has no problem when view in image editor(pic.1). But when I view them in other software after save as png, they disappear or look very strange(pic.2).
Can anyone solve this? I export a lot of png in my workflow because I have to ps render on photos. Sorry for my English.
[image: When view inside blender]

[image: When view in other software]

Comment: OK got it, something to do with my material.

Comment: I'd need more information, bc. I'm not sure what the problem is, but it seems you saved the png without alpha

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Thank you for answering, it happens that my material is a no noise glass material I downloaded online, it doesn't render alpha pass correctly.

Comment: Just curious: why use a downloaded glass material? No noise in the shadows? Anyways, watch captain disillusion's alpha channel rant on youtube, it should help.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Yup, that's why. Blender guru's glass material, said to reduce render time a lot. New to blender so I downloaded it. Thanks for the youtube recommend! This community is great!